# How to use string assignment structure?

Tags: c

the codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct super_block {
        unsigned short s_ninodes;
        unsigned short s_nzones;
};

#define NR_SUPER 8
struct super_block super_block[NR_SUPER];

int
main()
{
        struct super_block * p;
        struct super_block * s;
        char b_data[] = "2020";

        for(p = &super_block[0] ; p < &super_block[NR_SUPER] ; p++) {
                p->s_ninodes= 0;
                p->s_nzones = 0;
        }

        s = super_block;

        *(s) = *((struct super_block *) b_data);
        printf("%d\n%d\n", s->s_ninodes, s->s_nzones);
        return 0;
}
```

The question is: I want to

```
s->s_ninodes =20 and s->s_nzones=20, how to solve it ?
```

Why `"*(s) = *((struct super_block *) b_data);"` is not ok?

Thank you

Comment: Did you read a good C programming book? Did you compile your code with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux)? Did you use a debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux) to run your code step by step?

Comment: `s = super_block;`?Is it legal in C?

Comment: the string literal `"20"` is not the same as the `unsigned short` value `20`.

Comment: @MyMNEeo: since `s` is a pointer and `super_block` an array of the same type, the assignment `s = superblock;` is legal.

Comment: `*(s) = *((struct super_block *) b_data);` It's not legal. If `b_data` hold unsigned short means, it will get valid.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I thought he has assigned a structure to a variable before I saw `struct super_block super_block[NR_SUPER];`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  CFLAGS="-Wall -g" make test2
cc -Wall -g    test2.c   -o test2 I use this. NOT warnning

Comment: @mani the code I learn from the kernel of linux 0.12. So the "*(s) = *((struct super_block *) b_data);" is ok. In the function of read_super() in super.c, "*((struct d_super_block *) s) =
  *((struct d_super_block *) bh->b_data);" I make it simple

Answer (score 2):

The array `b_data` is 5 bytes long ("2020" => 4 chars plus the ending `\0`).
Assuming your structure is packed, and that `sizeof(short) == 2`, your `struct superblock` object will receive the byte value of the characters in the string. Here, given common ASCII value, you are likely to get (in hexadecimal fashion to avoid endianness discussion) `s->s_ninodes == s->s_nzones == 0x6260`.

If you want to stick with this fuzzy method to affect data to your structure, then just try with `short b_data[] = {20,20}` instead, and pray that your structure is packed ... (or add an `__attribute__((packed))` token). Anyway, it's a *very bad* practice to make such affectations without a good reason to do so (generally, the good reason being the retrieval of a data stream that needs parsing, and, in this case you are most likely to find the `__attribute__((packed))` stuff in the data structure definitions).

*EDIT* : I don't know why, but when doing such things, it appears to me that using `memcpy()` instead of the straightforward affectation makes it clearer (easier to read and spot buffer overflows I guess).

Comment: Thank you. "*((struct d_super_block *) s) = *((struct d_super_block *) bh->b_data);" I want to check this code which is in read_super() in the super.c of kernel 0.12. the type of bh->b_data is "char *" , So I want to try it.